# Android Studio stuck indefinitely during gradle sync, but the same project works fine in Intellij Idea

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on a mid sized project which has 30 modules. These modules depend on external libraries some of which are hosted on a private maven repository while the others are from mavenCentral(). I am using Android Studio 1.4 and IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 14.1.5. I am facing a strange problem that if I open my project in AS 1.4, it is indefinitely stuck on gradle sync. Like the project won't sync at all. I have waited for hours and hours, given 4 GB heap space to AS, basically done everything in my power but AS refuses to sync the project. On the other hand, the project works completely fine with IntelliJ Idea. It syncs within 30 seconds on it. 
What am I missing? Has anyone else faced this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably getting stuck looking for a repository or artifact. Run it on the command line where you can look at the logs from the dependency resolution.

`gradle clean build --stacktrace`

Tracking down the missing dependency should be simple once you know what gradle is looking for and where gradle is looking for it.

Comment: As I pointed out, the same project works perfectly fine in IntelliJ. So the problem lies somewhere in AS.

Comment: @Bhoot, So it works via command line?  If yes and it only fails in AS then check the AS logs to see if any errors are thrown. `Help -> Show Logs In Finder`

Comment: Yes, the project works from command line. It is important to note that gradle sync does not have anything to with the gradle build system in general. Gradle sync is for the IDE to reflect the project structure. Regarding logs, absolutely no logs are generated at the time AS is stuck doing a gradle sync.

Comment: @Bhoot, gradle sync definitely executes the initialization and configuration phases of gradle.  This is required to setup the project within the IDE.  During the sync `settings.gradle` will be evaluated to determine what modules are in the build and the `build.gradle` will be evaluated to find dependencies and configure modules.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I fail to understand why AS runs into problem while trying to resolve dependencies and IntelliJ does not. Also, I am so desperate to use AS 1.4 because unlike latest IntelliJ it supports downloading sources for AAR dependencies.

Comment: In 2019 with Android Studio 3.5.3, `gradle` command is now `gradlew`. You run this command under project root.